# How do I find WINE

Tags: wine

I'm trying to change the settings for WINE, but there's a problem...I can't find it lol (sorry just my sense of humor) but seriously though, I want to get WINE to use a virtual desktop, but everytime I type WINE into the search bar it's not there, it's clearly installed though because I can run Sonic Adventure DX and other Windows programs (by the way I'm amazed, I barely notice a difference in running it on Windows and running it on WINE) but I'm trying to run it in a virtual desktop. the WINEhq I have installed is the latest WINE staging and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. My issue is I just can't find the app, and when I right click on a .exe file I see that circle thing with the line threw it instead of a glass of wine, hopes this info helps on helping me lol

Comment: Have you tried opening a terminal and typing `winecfg`? Wine is a moving target so I'm not sure this works in 16.04, hence posting it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: That helped, so thank you, I would consider that an answer in some way lol, thank you

Comment: you could install locate... `sudo apt install locate && sudo updatedb` then search for wine with something like `locate wine` or `locate wine |grep bin`

Comment: OK, I'll post it then. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to start the Wine configuration utility by opening a terminal and typing `winecfg`.